# Windows Store Binding Issue

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Store project as follows:

```
class MyModel
{
    private int _testVar;
    public int TestVariable
    {
        get { return _testVar; }
        set
        {
            _testVar = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TestVariable");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }


}
```

My binding is as follows:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestVariable}" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
    MyModel thisModel = new MyModel();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        thisModel.TestVariable = 0;
        DataContext = thisModel;
    }
```

As this point, the binding appears to work as I get the textblock showing a 0.  However, when I handle the button click event as follows:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        thisModel.TestVariable++;
    }
```

I don't see the number increasing.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your class doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
I mean I expected to see `class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

First, the view model must implement INotifyPropertyChanged or better use some kind of MVVM Library like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), this will help you a lot.
Second, I'm not sure, if the call thisModel.TestVariable++ actually updates the value? Try to use thisModel.TestVariable = thisModel.TestVariable + 1;

Comment: There is no doubt that ++ will raise PropertyChanged.

Comment: I can confirm that thisModel.TestVariable++ does work fine once I implemented INotifyPropertyChnaged